# The relationship between root hermite factor and bit-security?

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

The root hermite factor corresponding to an bit-security level, such as 1.0045 corresponding to 128-bit security. What is the root hermite factor corresponding to 100-bit, 160-bit, 180-bit security?

root hermite factor: 1.0045     ?      ?      ?
bit-security       :   128     100    160    180